# VM image distribution of a Kerberos server?

Tags: gratis, virtual-machine

[Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) is a server-side technology which is quite [tricky to set up](http://techpubs.spinlocksolutions.com/dklar/kerberos.html).

Many developers have to install one in order to develop/test Kerberos support in their products.

Is there a distribution that includes a test Kerberos server out of the box, with zero configuration needed?

Ideally it would be available as a VM image.

TurnKey Linux does this kind of things (for instance see their [Turnkey Domain Controller](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller)), but they unfortunately offer no Turnkey Kerberos.

Must be free, or at least have a free trial period. Ideally open source, but that's not a hard requirement.
Virtualbox-compatible images are best, but otherwise any OS is fine, even hosted or mobile (never know) offers.

Comment: Anything wrong with this [sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kerberos-server-vm/) - if not why don't you just use that as the answer; you *should* be able to give it a good review eh :p

Comment: @NickWilde: I don't trust the maintainer of that project haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding no distribution for this, I have created my own distribution:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/kerberos-server-vm/

I am still very open to other answers, because:

- I don't have time to maintain this distribution properly
- I haven't tested it well
- It has very little traffic, and zero community

I am also open to letting someone take over this project, please contact me.